# Translating android phone number label id to string

Tags: uri, addressbook, android

Hi Im writing a small android app that is closely working whit phone labels but I don't understand how I'm suposed to translate the uri values described in the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.html).

What i want to do is to translate `TYPE_HOME` To `Home` and so on. My current solution is to have a list of all translated string but it has presented a lot of problem with languish. But i want to be able to do it like the addresbook and other apps doses it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Android has a built in method to do this already ...

```
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;
String s = (String) Phone.getTypeLabel(context.getResources(), Phone.TYPE_HOME, "");
```

Comment: Yay!! You maid my day. Where did you learn about this? (always good to know for future reference)

Comment: I stumbled upon it while reading the ContactsContract documentation while doing something similar to you.

Comment: One question what is context.getResources() ?

Comment: sorry, Context is explained here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html.

If you are doing this stuff in an activity or service, use 'this' in place for context.

Comment: I got it `Phone.getTypeLabel(this.getResources(), Phone.TYPE_HOME, "");`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there're no resources for labels. You can only have all strings as resources in your own app and convert default types to these strings.

**UPDATE**: There're a lot of solutions for converting label type to string. For example, you can define `string-array` resource:

```
<string-array name="labels">
    <item>@string/phone</item>
    <item>@string/mobile</item>
    <item>@string/work</item>
</string-array>
```

Then you should define these string for all languages you support. You'll be able to convert label code to string after loading this array with `getResources().getTextArray(R.array.labels)`. Also you have to deal with custom labels.

That's a possible solution but in fact everything depends on your app's architecture.

Comment: I said that I am doing it myself but i don't what to. To avoid languish problems.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [the source code for `ContactsListActivity`](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts/blob/master/src/com/android/contacts/ContactsListActivity.java), it appears that the Android developers just mapped values like `Phone.TYPE_MOBILE` to values they defined in strings.xml, just for that app, indicating there is no universal system label to easily lookup (for example, as one might use `@android:drawable` to use system graphics, which is not a recommended practice, as the images change between platforms).

Comment: Hum... I had a look in the xml file but there wear no values that corresponded to `Phone.TYPE_MOBILE` or any one else. but it had call mobile and sms... You get at vote up but its not the full solution to my problem

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get localized phone type string with the code:

```
int phoneNumberType = (int)pCur.getInt(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.getTypeLabel(context.getResources(), phoneNumberType , "")
```

but for custom phone types you should cosider phone label, not only phone type:

```
String phoneLabel = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL));
```